# Codeigniter Clone Data from table and update it

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**What i am trying to do:** 
Try to Clone Data (Update) from Table "Payment" to "Payment History"

**Payment Table**

```
Payment_ID
Payment_Amount
Payment_Method
Payment_Remark
```

**Payment History Table**

```
Payment_ID
PaymentHistory_ID
Payment_Amount
Payment_Method
Payment_Remark
```

Both have the same column and same data type

My Code: 
 **Controller**

```
    public function updateHistory($Payment_ID){

  $this->db->select('*'); 
  $this->db->from('Payment');   
  $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID); 
$query = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->update('PaymentHistory',$query);

}
```

Comment: you want to copy data from Payment table to Payment history table?

Comment: yeah , depending on the "Payment_ID"  , when i access to specific payment_ID i have the option to "copy the data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$query = $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->get('Payment');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {      
      $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $row->Payment_ID)->update('PaymentHistory', $row); // To update existing record
      //$this->db->insert('PaymentHistory',$row); // To insert new record
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the kindly help , but I have a problem is that what if for my payment history table there is "PaymentHistory_ID" , how should I do it? I have updated the question

Comment: what is the purpose of `PaymentHistory_ID` column?

Comment: Sorry for the late response , i am able to done the code with your help . But i am facing a new problem , i will create new question to prevent any confusion for future reader