# Codeigniter - Clone Data (But remove 1 column that is not exist )

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**What i am trying to do:** 
Try to Clone Data (Update) from Table "Payment History" to "Payment"  , But the problem right now is that in **Payment History Table** there is "PaymentHistory_ID" column , how do I ignore it ?

**Payment Table**

```
Payment_ID
Payment_Amount
Payment_Method
Payment_Remark
```

**Payment History Table**

```
Payment_ID
PaymentHistory_ID
Payment_Amount
Payment_Method
Payment_Remark
```

Both have the same column and same data type

My Code: 
 **Controller**

```
        public function updateHistory($Payment_ID){

$query = $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->get('PaymentHistory');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {      
      $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $row->Payment_ID)->update('PaymentHistory', $row); // To update existing record
      //$this->db->insert('Payment',$row); // To insert new record
}

    }
```

Based on the question that I have provided
[Codeigniter Clone Data from table and update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863760/codeigniter-clone-data-from-table-and-update-it/56864028?noredirect=1#comment100278815_56864028)
, the codes works , but not the new problem that I am facing.

Note: New to CodeIgniter

Comment: PaymentHistory_ID is it autoincrement value or null value ?

Comment: Auto-Increment value

Comment: you ca pass $this->db->select('Payment_ID','Payment_Amount','Payment_Method','Payment_Remark');

Comment: @pointydynamo , Sorry about that , i have updated to the latest code (copied wrong code section when i tried to ask a new question)

Comment: but you did not use select while get Payment table data

Answer (score 0):

**with single Payment_ID**

```
public function updateHistory($Payment_ID){
        // with single Payment_ID

        //get data with specific column and ignore PaymentHistory_ID
        $query = $this->db->select('Payment_Amount','Payment_Method','Payment_Remark')->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->get('YOUR FROM TABLE');
        $result = $query->row_array();

        if($result)
        { // check if has data
            //then update to another table
            $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->update('YOUR TO TABLE', $result ); // To update existing record
        }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response , the query works , ( have success message , no any error) but in my DB it won't change the data

Comment: which function did you use? single or multiple

Comment: single function

Comment: try change $result = $query->row();  to  $result = $query->row_array();

Comment: Nope , still not working , no error message , just the db won't change

Comment: change to select('Payment_Amount','Payment_Method','Payment_Remark') and try  i just updated ans please check