# PHP Codeigniter - Clone Data ( Works for only 1 single row , but not all row )

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**What i am trying to do:** 
Try to Clone Data (Update) from Table "Payment History" to "Payment"  , But the problem right now is that in when i only select('Payment_Amount'), it works(update) but not everything , any idea ?

**Payment Table**

```
Payment_ID
Payment_Amount
Payment_Method
Payment_Remark
```

**Payment History Table**

```
Payment_ID
PaymentHistory_ID
Payment_Amount
Payment_Method
Payment_Remark
```

Both have the same column and same data type

My Code: 
 **Controller**

```
public function updateHistory($Payment_ID){
        // with single Payment_ID

        //get data with specific column and ignore PaymentHistory_ID
        $query = $this->db->select('Payment_Amount','Payment_Method','Payment_Remark')->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->get('YOUR FROM TABLE');
        $result = $query->row_array();

        if($result)
        { // check if has data
            //then update to another table
            $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->update('YOUR TO TABLE', $result ); // To update existing record
        }
}
```

Based on the question that I have provided
[Codeigniter - Clone Data (But remove 1 column that is not exist )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865973/codeigniter-clone-data-but-remove-1-column-that-is-not-exist/56866222?noredirect=1#comment100283545_56866222)
, the codes works , but not the new problem that I am facing.

Note: New to CodeIgniter

Comment: Is the provided code your final code, or just an example? If it's final, don't forget to change 'YOUR FROM TABLE' to Payment History, and 'YOUR TO TABLE' to Payment. If this however is just an example code, maybe update your question to provide the real function that produces the error, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(!empty($result)) { 
     $this->db->where('Payment_ID', $Payment_ID)->update('YOUR TO TABLE', $result[0]); // To update existing record
    }
```